# Possible lambda conflict in Synclock and Parallel.for

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, parallel.foreach

In the following nested loop containing a parallel.for, is it appropriate to use the lambda counter "j1" inside the synclock below?  The code seems to work -- but I don't know if I am losing any information.

```
For i = 1 to Cnt

   ... a lot of code here

   Parallel.For(1, N + 1, Sub(j1)
                     Dim temp As Double = 0
                     temp += a * b * x(j1, i)
                     SyncLock lock
                        y(j1, i) += temp
                     End SyncLock
                End Sub)
Next i
```

I would rather use the parallel.for for the outside loop in "i", but don't know how lambda affects all that work?

Answer (score 1):

The use of j1 is appropriate for this situation.  I suspect your gains are minimal if any because of the code you have in the lambda statement.  The Synclock essentially turns it into executing almost synchronously.  I would test performance and likely do just a simple For loop.  If you had more processing to do before the Synclock, you would probably start to see gains in performance.  Other than that, I don't see anything that WOULDN'T function correctly.

Putting the Parallel.For on the outside loop would probably increase performance, but the entire method would have to be included in the Lambda statement.